# How to take value from Array

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

i've an array

```
let pNo = parcelArr[indexPath.section]

print(pNo)  //the value I printed out (
    1000000026
)
```

After that I for loop the array

```
for value in pNo{
    print(value)
}
```

But it show me this error message:
**type any does not conform to protocol sequence**

And I would like to display the value in

```
cell.parcelNoLbl.text = value
```

Comment: `pNo` is not an array, as you print it looks like an Int? `parcelArr` is your array, it should be `cell.parcelNoLbl.text = pNo`?

Comment: Cast it as an array. `if let pNo = pNo as? [Int]` then loop.

Answer (score 0):

how many section do you have??
what is declaration of parcelArr ?? 
i think that is simple array

var  parcelArr : [Int]

you must use parcelArr[indexPath.row].

Edit:

Your parcelArr must be 2D array like this:

```
let parcelArr : [[Int]] = [[1000000026], [1000000027], [1000000028]]
```

Answer (score -1):

cell.parcelNoLbl.text = pNo[indexpath.row]

Try this

Comment: it show this error: type any has no subscript members

Comment: cell.parcelNoLbl.text = pNo[indexpath.row] as? String